# Correct way to use switch and voltage sensor in Simulink Simscape

Tags: simulink, simscape

I am trying to use a switch in Simulink Simscape.  I want to see what voltage appears on both sides of the switch.  The switch should close when the applied physical signal is greater than the threshold of the switch.  It should be open otherwise.  The switch is connected to a voltage source on one side and is an open circuit on the other side.

The voltage on the side connected to the voltage source is the voltage of the voltage source (as expected).  However, I find that when the switch is open, the voltage on the other side is not zero, it is the voltage of the voltage source.

The only way to get this to work (to get a near zero value for the output voltage) is to apply a non-infinite resistance between the terminal on the left hand side of the switch.

What's going on here?

In the real world, the voltage between ground and the left hand side switch terminal should be zero, not 12.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your simscape model there is problem of connection of voltage sensor because always voltage is measure across variable and current us measure through variable.

In your model Voltage Sensor3 is connected across variable but Voltage sensor4 is connected through variable (means connected through voltage source).

In shown  [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JPJB.jpg) I modeled your circuit Voltage Sensor3 should be connected like that way